# Enable library as Catalog... What does enable anonymous access do?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, cross-site-publishing

After checking off "Enable this library as a catalog" there is a button called Enable Anonymous Access.

When I click on it I get the message:

> Enabling anonymous access will override permission settings and allow
>   users who aren't logged in to view this content. Do you want to turn
>   on anonymous access?

What does it mean "users who aren't logged in"?  Every user is logged in via Active Directory when they sign into their computer, aren't they?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not for the computer, it is for the content from this catalog in SharePoint site.

Naturally, we need to sign in to the SharePoint site to access the content within the site. When enabling anonymous access, people don't need to sign in to access the content from this catalog.

If you don’t want anonymous users to view and search this content, in the Anonymous Access section, select Disable anonymous access.